# Finding the next cell that isn't highlighted (non-conditional)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to setup a formula that will find the next value that isn't highlighted using a search box entry on a userform.  Here's my basic formula so far:

```
Private Sub PrintButton1_Click()
With Worksheets(1).Range("a2:a10000")
Dim c As Range
     Set c = .Find(ScanBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then  'I think this is possibly where I should have the search condition?
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            MsgBox "Found It!"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            GoTo DoneFinding
        End If
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
End If
DoneFinding:
MsgBox "Nothing found!"
End With
End Sub
```

I've tried adding something like "And c.Interior.ColorIndex = 0" or "And c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone" but I don't think this is able to do what I'm thinking it should...

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the job. Please try it.

```
Sub PrintButton1_Click()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim FirstFound As String
    Dim Msg As String

    With Worksheets(1)
        ' set the range from A2 to the last used cell in column A
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), LastCell)
    End With

    Set FoundCell = Rng.Find(What:=ScanBox1.Text, After:=LastCell)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then FirstFound = FoundCell.Address

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        If FoundCell.Interior.Pattern <> -4142 Then
            Msg = "First highlighted cell is " & FoundCell.Address
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set FoundCell = Rng.FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
        Debug.Print FoundCell.Address
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do
    Loop

    If Len(Msg) = 0 Then Msg = "No match highlighted matching cell was found."
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation, "Search result"
End Sub
```

Comment: I just notice that my solution finds highlighted cells instead of those which are not. Please replace `If FoundCell.Interior.Pattern <> -4142 Then` with `If FoundCell.Interior.Pattern = -4142 Then` and adjust the output texts (which you probably don't need anyway).